# innerHTML not affecting div

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a problem with innerHTML
I'm trying to replace all child elements of a div (wipe it out) and replace with a text. Just to give you idea, this is a registration form, after clicking submit, it should clear the form and output some text. It looks like it doesn't take any affect on the div that I am targeting

here is the function

```
function signup() {
    var u = _("username").value;
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p1 = _("pass1").value;
    var p2 = _("pass2").value;
    var c = _("country").value;
    var g = _("gender").value;
    var status = _("status");
    if (u == "" || e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == "" || c == "" || g == "") {
        status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    } else if (p1 != p2) {
        status.innerHTML = "Your password fields do not match";
    } else if (_("terms").style.display == "none") {
        status.innerHTML = "Please view the terms of use";
    } else {
        _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
        status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if (ajax.responseText.trim() != "signup_success") {
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    _("signupform").innerHTML = "OK " + u + ", check your email inbox and junk mail box at <u>" + e + "</u> in a moment to complete the sign up process by activating your account. You will not be able to do anything on the site until you successfully activate your account.";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("u=" + u + "&e=" + e + "&p=" + p1 + "&c=" + c + "&g=" + g);
}
```

and here is the form:

```
<form name="signupform" id="signupform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div>Username: </div>
    <input id="username" type="text" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')" maxlength="16">
    <span id="unamestatus"></span>
    <div>Email Address:</div>
    <input id="email" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88">
    <div>Create Password:</div>
    <input id="pass1" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Confirm Password:</div>
    <input id="pass2" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Gender:</div>
    <select id="gender" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="m">Male</option>
        <option value="f">Female</option>
    </select>
    <div>Country:</div>
    <select id="country" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
        <?php include_once( "php_includes/template_country_list.php"); ?>
    </select>
    <div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="openTerms()">
        View the Terms Of Use
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="terms" style="display:none;">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>Please read the Terms and Conditions (opens a new window)</h3>
        <a href="iLOVEiTtermsandCONS.pdf" title="Terms and Conditions" target="_blank">
            <p>Terms and Conditions</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button id="signupbtn" onclick="signup()">Create Account</button>
    <span id="status"></span>
</form>
```

any ideas what could be wrong? I'm not good with java script at all
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forgot to mention, instead of having the message "check your email inbox and junk mail ..." I have the form as it was with only ajax message displayed "signup_success". Also it passes all data to mySQL and it sends the email as it should, only not displaying message.

Comment: what is the function _ ?

Comment: can you tell me what is the result of this code `ajax.responseText.trim() != "signup_success"`? if it's true, then could you try to use !== instead of != and then tell me what is the output.

Comment: @kucing_terbang It's true and it it should run the next line of it but it doesn't. I have tried your suggestion, nothing changed. It only displays string message "signup_success"

Comment: so if the output is true, then the ajax.responseText.trim() is not "signup_success" ? could you try see what the value actually is?

Comment: ok, then if it's false, it should modify the innerHTML. could you check the web console and see whether there is an error?

Comment: it's freaking me out. the console not showing any errors

Comment: ok this is my last suggestion ;), try to add an alert in the else function and check whether it got called or not. if not then try clean the cache and try this again. because from what i have seen it should be working.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, but that didn't work either. It looks like it's not passing to the else statement. So it clearly comes up TRUE. Alert wasn't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what does `_(" ").value` mean. But if you change this style to `document.getElementByid(" ")`, it works.

Comment: it's basically shorten version of document.getElementByid(" ") I call this function by _(" ")

Comment: Did you make a function like this? `var _ = function(id){ return document.getElementById(id);};`

Comment: function _(x){
  return document.getElementById(x);
 }

Comment: Your code seems okay. But I can test it until 'please wait' message. Check your .php file again.

Comment: php is fine no errors it's js. I got a feeling it's a silly typo but can't find anything. Console is not displaying any errors.

Comment: According to your comment on your question, it goes to 'else{}' but '_("signupform").innerHTML' doesn't work?

Comment: As I've mentioned above, it's actually not passing the else statement it returns TRUE. So there has to be a bug within that if statement.

Comment: Then, if statement runs? you can check it with the function like alert(). if true, check 'ajax.responseText.trim()' this value

Comment: Yeah, you means ajax.responseText.trim() is not '"signup_success", so you need to check ajax.responseText.trim()